# How to obtain sum of all numbers with given digits?

Tags: software-design

Suppose I am given a number say,285. I have to find the sum of all possible combinations of the digits in the number. In this case we have 285 + 258 + 825 + 852 + 582 + 528. 
I can use the itertools.permutations but it will take a lot of time to run. How do I solve this efficiently??

Comment: what have you trued? what language are you using? can you post some code?

Comment: I used python and its itertools library.

Comment: And what have you tried apart from itertools? Code?

Comment: That's what I am trying to know. What can I try apart from this naive solution